# Unable to start the Phusion Passenger - wrong root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, redmine

I'm trying to start up Redmine using [their guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/InstallRedmineOnDebianStableApacheMysqlPassenger) but I end up being unable to start up apache with Passenger. Errorl log:

```
[Thu Jun 06 19:56:01 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jun 06 19:56:03 2013] [error] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable (/usr/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'PassengerRoot' directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion Passenger or fix your 'PassengerRoot' directive, whichever is applicable.
[Thu Jun 06 19:56:03 2013] [error] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable (/usr/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'PassengerRoot' directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion Passenger or fix your 'PassengerRoot' directive, whichever is applicable.
[Thu Jun 06 19:56:03 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.5 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1e configured -- resuming normal operations
```

passenger.load

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/phusion-passenger/
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby/
PassengerDefaultUser www-data
```

And

```
# find / -name PassengerWatchdog
/usr/lib/phusion-passenger/agents/PassengerWatchdog
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5/agents/PassengerWatchdog
```

Where is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two Phusion Passenger installations. One installed with YUM/APT, the other with RubyGems. Remove everything, then install Phusion Passenger from scratch. See http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#uninstalling

Comment: Reinstall did not help. I can't still figure out, why it is trying to search Watchdog agent under that weird path, that I can't find defined anywhere. EDIT: Just found that I was editing .load file, but that config was inside .config file...